# How to iterate over dynamic rows in DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data frame, I want to iterate all the rows dynamically, to find bytes and convert them to float

Example

```
col1                          col2                        col3
None                          None                        b'R\xb8\x1e%\xda\x16QA'
b'R\xb8\x1e%\xda\x16QA'       b'R\xb8\x1e%\xda\x16QA'     None
None                          None                        None
b'R\xb8\x1e%\xda\x16QA'       None                        None
b'R\xb8\x1e%\xda\x16QA'       None                        b'R\xb8\x1e%\xda\x16QA'
```

Mi function bytes to float

```
def bytes2float(byte):
    if byte:
        # do stuff
```

I want to iterate over all the rows, because the DataFrame is dynamic
at the moment I can only do it statically, because I know how many columns the DataFrame has.

Something like that

```
for index, row in mydf.iterrows():
    # print(row['col1'], row['col2'])
    bytes2float(row['col1'])
    bytes2float(row['col2'])
    bytes2float(row['col3'])
    ... 
    ...
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over `mydf.columns`

```
for index, row in mydf.iterrows():
    for col in mydf.columns:
        bytes2float(row[col])
```

If you want to run the method `bytes2float` on every column of every row then you can use `applymap`

Sample:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(2,3))
print (df.applymap(lambda x: f"*{x}*"))
```

Output:

```
     0    1    2
0  *0*  *1*  *2*
1  *3*  *4*  *5*
```